# Sum all distinct values in a data frame

Tags: r

[Data Drame: Drugs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Ofg.png)

I would like to calculate the percent of arrests on drugs for each age. using age_num and on_drugs(1 = on drugs, 0 = not on drugs). Im not really sure where to start, so would appreciate any help. I thought about using a while loop, but not sure if thats the best approach or not. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) to group by and calculate summary measures. You can use the [%>%](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html)(pipe) operator to chain operations together.

Then you could do something like:

```
library(dplyr)

drugs %>%
  group_by(age_num) %>%
  summarise(pct_on_drugs = mean(on_drugs) * 100)
```

(note: you don't provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example-aka-mcve-minimal-complete-and-ver), so this snippet is not tested).